# How to add DockerEvents to my Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Dockerode and now I want to implement a listener so I have founded [docker-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-events) but when I want to use it I got this error :

```
ReferenceError: DockerEvents is not defined
```

My code look like this :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  //publish the collection
  Meteor.publish('infosContainers', function readInfosContainers() {
    return InfosContainers.find({});
  });
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log("startup server");
  //at the start I create the docker object
  docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});

  //create the docker events
  emitter = new DockerEvents({
    docker: new Dockerode(docker),
  });

  //maybe I need to create it like this
  emitter = new DockerEvents(docker);
  //start the emitter
    emitter.start();
});

/**
* this method listen if a container Start
**/
emitter.on("start", function(message) {
  console.log("container started: %j", message);
});
```

Someone know what I'm doing wrong ?  Thank you for the help

Comment: It seems like you didn't load the module or assigned it to variable other than `DockerEvents`. Do you know how to load modules in Node.js?

Comment: Not really but its with 'x require(something)' , but if I read the docker-event github page I can see that docker-event is in Dockerode and I can use dockerode because I can list my containers, stop them, start them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist, i.e. you don't have `var DockerEvents = ...;` anywhere.

I assume you load `dockerode` like this:

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
```

If you want to use `docker-events`, you have to do the same:

```
var DockerEvents = require('docker-events');
```

`require('modulename')` is how you load modules in Node.js.

How to use `docker-event` is already described in its documentation:

```
var emitter = new DockerEvents({
  docker: docker, // since you defined docker earlier
});
```

Comment: To create docker I did `var docker;
  docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});
`

Comment: I got this error : `Error: Can't find npm module 'docker-events'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?`

Comment: Seems like you haven't installed `docker-events`. You need to install it if you want to use it., just like with any other npm module.